# Can't see printed values if launch script with `java`

Tags: clojure

I have this code:

```
(ns test
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println "hello!"))
```

But when I run `java -cp clojure-1.6.0/clojure-1.6.0.jar clojure.main test.clj` I get no output. Why? How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `ns` and `defn` do not output anything. If you would like to print `"hello!"` by invoking the `-main` function, you have to add a function call at the end of the `test.clj` file.

```
(ns test
  (:gen-class))

(defn -main
  [& args]
  (println "hello!"))

(-main)
```

Comment: i think this is ok for simple programs, but normally you don't want to invoke `-main` (or anything else really) explicitly in code. `-main` is a special function and both `clojure.main` (via `-m`) and `lein run` provide facilities for executing `-main`. (also, in large code bases you might have many `-main` functions).

Answer (score 5):

You call the `-main` function like so:

```
java -cp clojure-1.6.0/clojure-1.6.0.jar clojure.main -i test.clj -m test
```

`-i` loads up a file

`-m` launches the `-main` function in a namespace